# SharePoint Online Classic Pages & O365 Group Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, calendar, office-365-groups

I have SP Online however due to master pages styling the requirement is to use classic pages, not modern.

I need to add a O365 Group calendar to the page. I know this is easily achieved in Modern pages.

Is there a work around to display the group calendar from O365 as a webpart? How do you add the connection? or does this have to be a custom build webpart?

Thanks

Comment: If my answer is useful and it helps you, please accept it as the "best answer". Thanks

Comment: Is it just me or is the web part widget to view the office 365 group calendar on a modern page useless? Doesn't even show a calendar shows an event view with the only option to edit the number of events shown from 1 - 10. Its as if the widget is 0.1% developed

Answer (score 0):

The Group Calendar web part is a modern web part. It cannot be used in a classic page. The modern pages can only use modern web parts and classic pages can only use classic web parts.

As an alternative, you can add the Group Calendar modern web part into a modern page and display this page on a classic page using iframe.

For example: Edit a classic page -> Embed code -> Insert following iframe script to the page.

```
<iframe src="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/<library>/<modern page>.aspx" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></iframe>
```

Otherwise, you need to develop a custom web part to achieve that.